# Different way to write Javascript?

Tags: javascript

It the code below I am not certain as to which way is better to write the code. The NewVar is a variable which I think can become which ever value is returned from the functions that are inside of the quotes. Is there a better way of writting this.

```
var NewVar = {
    myVar: function() {
        return AnotherValue;
    },
    isAny: function() {
            return SomeValue;
    }
};
```

Can you make the like this: Would the following work the same.

```
 var NewVar;

         function myFunc() {
            //code here
         }

         function myFunc2() {
            //code here
         }

   NewVar = myFunc();
```

or

```
   NewVar = myFunc2();
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to accomplish here. The first block of example code creates an object that is stored in NewVar. The functions you define in that object can than be called, but the returned values will not be set in NewVar, because that is the object containing the functions itself. So if you call var returnedValue = NewVar.myVar(), the value will be set in returnedValue, not in NewVar.

Answer (score 0):

> The NewVar is a variable which I think can become which ever value is returned from the functions

No. `NewVar` is a variable that gets assigned an object literal that contains these two functions as properties. You can invoke them as methods (without changing `NewVar`):

```
console.log(NewVar.isAny()); // SomeValue
console.log(NewVar.myVar()); // AnotherValue
```

Your second snippet is totally different from that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question.

In your first snippet NewVar is a **object** which contains two *methods* (myVar and isAny) so I can do something like:

```
var foo = NewVar.myVar();
```

In the second snippet you are declaring two functions and then you assign to `NewVar` the return value of one of these functions.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, these two examples are different. In the first example, you can call `myVar` and `isAny` as a member of `NewVar`:

```
NewVar.myVar(); // returns AnotherValue
NewVar.isAny(); // returns SomeValue
```

But in the second example, you assign the return value of the functions to the variable `NewVar`. For example, look at this example:

```
var myObject = {
    addUp: function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }
};

myObject.addUp(1, 2); // returns 3
var myVar = myObject.addUp(1, 2); // myVar holds 3, because myObject.addUp(1,2) returns 3
```